# How to open Autodesk BIM360 video file in html5 video player?

Tags: html5-video, video.js, autodesk-bim360

I am using Video.js library for my video player.The video source is coming from Autodesk BIM360 Docs and that needs authentication. 
How can I open BIM360 video file in my video player?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

For this you need to get the endpoint of video and request with headers Authorization: Bearer

The way you get end point is from forge [Data Management Api](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2), you can list Hubs > Projects > Folders > Items > Versions.

A file can have 1+ versions, so that's why you need the specific version. [This tutorial](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels) guides you on the steps.

Once you get the version, check the relationship.storage.data.id
for ex it will be like this:

"id": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/9f8bdc3f-e29c-4ada-ab7b-bb8dfa821163.pdf"

Take the last part of the above id and form the endpoint like below shown, 
your video endpoint becomes: 
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/9f8bdc3f-e29c-4ada-ab7b-bb8dfa821163.mp4

here is the api for reference: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-GET/

When using video.js library after src, set headers as shown below:

`let mp4 = {
 src:  "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/9f8bdc3f-e29c-4ada-ab7b-bb8dfa821163.mp4",
  "headers": {
   "authorization": "Bearer token
 }
 type: "video/mp4"
};`

Comment: please go through the question once again which i asked that's not related to accessing BIM360 file.

Comment: hi chaitra, to access any bim360 docs file you need authentication, from the sample you take only accessing files part, not the whole thing. please let me know if you still have doubt.

Comment: i have posted my issue above.

Comment: i have edited the answer with all the details, this should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176298/discussion-between-varunpatil-and-chitra).